# How to explain that error at RStudio startup when redefining base::setwd() in a package loaded in .Rprofile?

Tags: r, rstudio

#### Setup

Inspired from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136059/how-to-show-working-directory-in-r-prompt)

I have some tools in a package called `consoleR`.

Inside this package, a `setwd` funciton is masking `base::setwd` in order to display the current directory in the prompt like this:

```
## file consoleR/R/setwd.R
#' @export
setwd <- function(...) {
  base::setwd(...)
  current_dir <- basename(getwd())
  options(prompt = paste(current_dir, " > "))
}
```

I load that package every session in my `.Rprofile`:

```
## file ~/.Rprofile
if(interactive()) {
  library(consoleR, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  setwd(getwd()) ## initializing the prompt
}
```

---

#### Issue

**When I start R from a nix-terminal everything works fine**, but when I start RStudio I got an error I cannot explain:

```
R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error in base::setwd(...) : character argument expected
project_dir >
```

---

#### Effort

Then I use `traceback()` and I get:

```
project_dir > traceback()
5: base::setwd(...) at setwd.R#10
4: setwd(owd)
3: .rs.onAvailablePackagesStale(reposString)
2: .rs.availablePackages()
1: .rs.rpc.discover_package_dependencies("353B2D06", ".R")
rstudio-available-packages-3178bc4c5ea9a2  >
```

Note that the prompt is showing another directory than the current one BEFORE and AFTER the call to `traceback`.

The current dir is in fact my `$HOME` dir.

---

What could be going on?

Comment: I would suggest that you don't mask `setwd` and do this instead: `trace(base::setwd, exit = quote(options(prompt = paste(basename(getwd()), " > "))), print = FALSE)`

Comment: @Roland Your implementation is of course better but, generally, why do you “strongly suggest” not to mask base functions? This *should* work, and generally *does*, unless you do something wrong (which you can still do with `trace()`), or some other code has glaring bugs.

Comment: Some comments on your code: (1) Calling `library` or similar in `.Rprofile` is asking for trouble. Instead, I recommend you modify `options('defaultPackages')`. (2) Since your package always needs to initialise the prompt, I suggest moving that code into the package’s `.onLoad` hook. And instead of calling `setwd(getwd())` there, just set the prompt directly. (3) Your package *overwrites* the user-defined prompt, which is usually unwanted. Instead, save the existing user prompt and *prefix* it with the WD. Or, even better, allow the user to supply a `sprintf`-like pattern and insert the WD.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't "generally" advise against masking base functions (although I usually hesitate doing that). I have already retracted the "strongly".

Comment: I was not aware of `trace` or `defaultPackages` or `.onLoad`! You made my day...

Comment: @Roland To clarify, my use of “generally” was intended as synonymous to “apart from that”; it wasn’t meant to suggest that you “generally” advise against doing X.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can you explain why a call to the `library` function in `.Rprofile` can cause problems even when used with `if(interactive)`?

Comment: @pietrodito Because it changes the order in which packages are loaded and attached. In particular, calling `library()` inside `.Rprofile` attaches that package *before* some of the core R packages, and this can lead to issues when packages redefine names that are also exported by core R packages. In your case this won’t happen (I guess: your `setwd` overwrites `base::setwd`, and the ‘base’ package is always attached first) so it’s not as important, but it still changes the order of `search()`, which may confuse other (poorly written) packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular `setwd` return a character string or `NULL` is the working directory is not available. Your `setwd` doesn't as the last statement is the call to `options` which returns a `list`. So the following will probably resolve this:

```
## file consoleR/R/setwd.R
#' @export
setwd <- function(...) {
  res <- base::setwd(...)
  current_dir <- basename(getwd())
  options(prompt = paste(current_dir, " > "))
  res
}
```

Edit: The return values of `setwd` and `options` are usually used to set the directory back afterwards:

```
function(...) {
  olddir <- setwd(newdir)
  on.exit(setwd(olddir))
  # do stuff
}
```

The `setwd` called in your example will then get a list which explains the error message.